# Find a substring and reposition it

Tags: java, string, substring

I am trying to find a substring in a string. If the string does not contains the substring it will be add at the back of the string. However, in some of the data the substring is in the middle (it is suppose to be at the back (address)).

```
boolean checkState = s.getAddress().contains("MELAKA");
String[] addr = s.getAddress().split(",");
String newTrimAddress = addr[0];

for (int i = 1; i < addr.length; i++) {
    boolean check = false;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < addr.length; j++) {
        if (addr[i].equals(addr[j])) {
            check = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (check == false) {
        newTrimAddress += ", " + addr[i];
    }
}

if (checkState == false)
    newTrimAddress += ", " + "MELAKA";

System.out.println(newTrimAddress);
```

Last but not least, if there is any way i can remove the 2nd or 3rd occurrence of a substring because the structure of the address is very bad. The city is redundance, and i can replace it because there are some of the house's address have the city name in it. Thank you.

Comment: Let me get this straight: if the substring occurs *multiple* times, you want to remove all these instances?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem lets say, i wanna remove it if it occur 3rd times. I only wanna remove the last one

Answer (score 0):

Java's substring method allows you to enter a start index and (optionally) an end index.  So, if you need to remove part of the middle, you can do a substring of the first part and concatenate it with a substring of the last part.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [String.replaceAll(String subString)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) ? 
This will allow you to replace the substring wherever it is. It also has the added benefit of finding any duplicates of the substring. You can also replace the string with an empty string and then prepend it how you like for example:

```
String trimmed = originalString.replaceAll("MELAKA", "");
String trimmed = trimmed + "," + "MELAKA";
```

Comment: I cant do that because some residential area's name contains the city name. eg: TAMAN MERLIMAU BARU (residential area), MERLIMAU (city)